# React Native: Invalid prop `transform` of type `string` supplied, expected an array

Tags: typescript, react-native, transform, translate, react-native-stylesheet

We are using the CSS style transform/translate parameters but this is invalid for React Native typescript.

```
 Invariant Violation: Invalid prop `transform` of type `string` supplied to `StyleSheet modalContent`, expected an array.
    StyleSheet modalContent: {
      "transform": "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }
```

What is the correct way to write this in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

I found the [official docs here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms).

These are the options for the array:

> ```
> [
>  {matrix: number[]}, 
>  {perspective: number}, 
>  {rotate: string}, 
>  {rotateX: string}, 
>  {rotateY: string}, 
>  {rotateZ: string}, 
>  {scale: number}, 
>  {scaleX: number}, 
>  {scaleY: number}, 
>  {translateX: number}, 
>  {translateY: number}, 
>  {skewX: string}, 
>  {skewY: string}
> ]
> ```

So in my case it would be:

```
transform: [
  {translateX: '-50%'}, 
  {translateY: '-50%'}
]
```